# Can't connect to Amazon S3 on scala. Python connection works well, but on Scala I am getting 403 Forbidden response

Tags: java, scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Also I have port number, but i didn't find where to set it. How can I fix this problem? Through python's "boto" client I successfully connected to my service, but on Scala it always returns forbidden message.

```
object a extends App{

      import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials

      val accessKey = "myAccessKey"
      val secretKey = "mySecretKey"
      val credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey)

      import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client

      val s3client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials)

      s3client.setEndpoint("address")

      val s3object = s3client.getObject("myBucket", "file.txt")

      println(s3object.getKey, s3object.getObjectMetadata.getLastModified)
    }
```

Here is error log:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID: null; S3 Extended Request ID: null), S3 Extended Request ID: null
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1639)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1304)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1056)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:743)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4319)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4266)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1406)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1267)
    at a$.delayedEndpoint$a$1(a.scala:17)
    at a$delayedInit$body.apply(a.scala:3)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:389)
    at scala.App.main(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App.main$(App.scala:74)
    at a$.main(a.scala:3)
    at a.main(a.scala)
```

Answer (score 0):

The AWS SDK somehow discourages using the `endpoint` ([JavaDoc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/client/builder/AwsClientBuilder.html#setEndpointConfiguration-com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration-)):

> Only use this if using a non-standard service endpoint - the recommended approach for configuring a client is to use {@link #withRegion(String)}

Instead, use the `withRegion`:

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.{AWSStaticCredentialsProvider, BasicAWSCredentials}
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client

AmazonS3Client.builder()
  .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(
    new BasicAWSCredentials("accessKey", "secretKey")))
  .withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1).build()
```